# How can I remove a unique constraint from a database column in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I created a table using the following migration:

```
class CreateProfilePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profile_pictures do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null: false
      t.integer :picture_id, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :profile_pictures, :user_id, unique: true
    add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

I tried to remove the constraint with the following:

```
class FixProfilePic < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :profile_pictures, :picture_id, :integer, unique: false
  end
end
```

I still get a unique constraint violation error if I try to use the same picture_id in more than one place. What is the proper way to remove the uniqueness constraint from  picture_id?

Comment: You need to remove the `index`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a problem with the accepted answer: Rollbacks don't work correctly as the unique index is not restored.

You could try this instead:

```rb
reversible do |dir|
  dir.up do
    remove_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
    add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
  end

  dir.down do
    remove_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
    add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the new answer

Answer (score 70):

You must remove your index with:

```
remove_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
```

and add it again with:

```
add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
```

[ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)

Comment: This no longer works. What works now is: `remove_index :profile_pictures, name: 'picture_id'`

Comment: Beware, a rollback of this migration won't restore the UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 11):

> add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id, unique: true

So update your index to:

```
  remove_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
  add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
```

I'm guessing this is it.

Answer (score 1):

For the migration to be reversible, you now (Rails 6+) need to use the `:column` option.

Adding `unique: true` also ensures rolling back the migration will recreate the index with the uniqueness constraint (barring problematic data being inserted in the meantime).

```
  remove_index :profile_pictures, column: :picture_id, unique: true
  add_index :profile_pictures, :picture_id
```

One more thing to note: if your table is large, then creating a new index on it could lock writes to it for a long time. Consider using `algorithm: :concurrently` if you use Postgres