# which migration do I run to change this line: t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to temporarily remove the uniqueness constraint on emails in my app. In my schema, the users table currently contains this following line - I'd like to change the true at the end:

```
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

I'm very unsure about which migration/syntax I need to run in order for the last part to be false. Is it:
`rails g migration change_column :users, :index_users_on_email, :index, unique: false`?
or is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated! I'm scared of messing things up in the db - still a beginner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a unique constraint from a database column in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495396/how-can-i-remove-a-unique-constraint-from-a-database-column-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggestion just removing the index and then adding one without an uniqueness constraint. After you are done doing what you need to do and want to re-add it, you can drop the index without the uniqueness constraint and re-add one with out

```
# first migration
remove_index :users, column: :index, unique: true
add_index :users, :index
```

And whenever you want to add it back

```
# second migration
remove_index :users, column: :index
add_index :users, :index, unique: true
```